# XP Pen Pentablet Config - decoding the config file

Tags: xml, keyboard, config, shortcut

Bought 5x XP-Pen tablets for work, but the crappy drivers won't save config files properly. 
specifically i want to change the keybindings for the hardware shortcut keys
Looked through the config files and identified the section of the file that governs the default shortcuts. What i can't figure out is what governs the actual keybinding.

```
<K1 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+S|83|31|2</K1>
```

i suspect the following:
first digit sets the 'mode' of the button: 0 is default binding, 1 is execute a program and 2 is keyboard shortcut.
The following string governs what the display overlay shows when you press a key
The digits control the actual keys. I thought this might be JS/DHTML key code values, but 'ctrl' is 17 in that standard, not 31.

```
<Shortcuts>
                    <K1 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+S|83|31|2</K1>
                    <K2 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+Z|90|44|2</K2>
                    <K3 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+Y|89|44|2</K3>
                    <K4 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+Shift+S||||3</K4>
                    <K5 SelectID="2">1|PGUP|33|329|0</K5>
                    <K6 SelectID="2">1|PGDOWN|34|337|0</K6>
                    <K7 SelectID="0"></K7>
                    <K8 SelectID="0"></K8>
                    <K9 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+S|83|31|2</K9>
                    <K10 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+Z|90|44|2</K10>
                    <K11 SelectID="2">1|Ctrl+Y|89|44|2</K11>
                    <K12 SelectID="2">2|0</K12>
                    <K13 SelectID="2">1|PGUP|33|329|0</K13>
                    <K14 SelectID="2">1|PGDOWN|34|337|0</K14>
                    <K15 SelectID="2">2|0</K15>
                    <K16 SelectID="2">2|0</K16>
                </Shortcuts>
```

If anyone is interested in the full config file, i can provide it. Header says it is XML aparrently.

Answer (score 0):

partial answer:
I have an XP-Pen Artist 22E-Pro.
This is for encoding the letter "a".

```
<K7 SelectID="2">1|A|65|30|0</K7>
```

You're right about the first and second entries.

```
<K8 SelectID="2">1|F12|123|88|0</K8>
```

Third entry is the JavaScript Event Keycode.
At least for one of the keys.

This was enough info for adding myself F13 to F24 keys.
So for example I changed key 8 to:

```
<K8 SelectID="2">1|F18|129|88|0</K8>
```

AutoHotkey confirms that they are working.
I have no idea, what the fourth column is about.
But I think the fifth is modifier state.
With 2 meaning ctrl being pressed and 0 meaning no modifiers.

Haven't confirmed this, though.